# Behaviour of printf using length subspecifier with a string

Tags: c, printf, undefined-behavior, libc, format-specifiers

I'm curious how work printf and I have try many tricks like :

```
printf("Test 1: %hs\n", "hi");
printf("Test 2: %hhs\n", "hi");
printf("Test 3: %ls\n", "hi");
printf("Test 4: %lls\n", "hi");
printf("Test 5: %js\n", "hi");
printf("Test 6: %zs\n", "hi");
printf("Test 7: %ts", "hi");
```

I'm using printf with `s` specifier and all length modifier (usually used with numerical speficier (like `d / i / u / o ...`) and i'm getting strange output :

```
Test 1: hi
Test 2: hi
Test 3: Test 4: Test 5: Test 6: hi
Test 7: hi
```

It seem's that the `l / ll / j` length modifiers make printf bug and stop to work (it doesn't print the `\n` but with all other length modifiers it seems to ignore the length modifier and work like normal usage).

Why it follow this behavior ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). The format specifier `%s` doesn't support any of the length modifiers you have used for the arguments you pass. Format specifier mismatch is undefined in C. When I compile your code with gcc compiler (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 test.c`), it says as much:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:5:19: warning: use of ‘h’ length modifier with ‘s’ type character has either no effect or undefined behavior [-Wformat=]
 printf("Test 1: %hs\n", "hi");
                   ^
test.c:6:20: warning: use of ‘hh’ length modifier with ‘s’ type character has either no effect or undefined behavior [-Wformat=]
 printf("Test 2: %hhs\n", "hi");
                    ^
test.c:7:19: warning: format ‘%ls’ expects argument of type ‘wchar_t *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat=]
 printf("Test 3: %ls\n", "hi");
                   ^
test.c:8:20: warning: use of ‘ll’ length modifier with ‘s’ type character has either no effect or undefined behavior [-Wformat=]
 printf("Test 4: %lls\n", "hi");
                    ^
test.c:9:19: warning: use of ‘j’ length modifier with ‘s’ type character has either no effect or undefined behavior [-Wformat=]
 printf("Test 5: %js\n", "hi");
                   ^
test.c:10:19: warning: use of ‘z’ length modifier with ‘s’ type character has either no effect or undefined behavior [-Wformat=]
 printf("Test 6: %zs\n", "hi");
                   ^
test.c:11:19: warning: use of ‘t’ length modifier with ‘s’ type character has either no effect or undefined behavior [-Wformat=]
 printf("Test 7: %ts", "hi");
```

Comment: *"... doesn't support any of the length modifiers ..."* - doesn't `%ls` mean a wide string?

Comment: "**...you have used for the arguments you pass.**". doesn't %ls mean a wide string?" - Yes.

Answer (score 2):

The only length modifier that's valid to use with `%s` is `l`, and it signifies that the argument has type `wchar_t`, not `char`.

None of `hh`, `h`, `ll`, `j`, `z`, or `t` are defined for use with `s`.

Please see the [C 2011 online standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), §7.21.6.1, para 7.